# simplest method to clear text field after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I've been searching all over the place to try and get my text field to clear after submit. Keep in mind that I want to stay on the
same page when data is being submitted (I have a jquery code for
staying on the same page after submission). I figured that it would be
a lot easier if I just posted my code so that I can get help in my
specific case. The following is what I tried, the .reset(), java
onclick, onsubmit, jquery and ajax methods and none of them have
produced the result that I am looking for. The closest I have gotten
was a form getting cleared before submit and this leaves a blank
submission.

Here's my form code for getting test info from the user. Here I tried the onclick, onsubmit methods without much luck:

```
        <form id=\"msg\"  method=\"post\" action=\"topage.php\" style=\"text-align: center; font-size: 26px; font-weight: bold; color: white; position: relative; top:  -45px\">
MESSAGE<br><input type=\"text\" style=\"font-size: 22px;width:90%; height:50px; resize: none; \" name=\"msg\" >
<input class=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Send\" style=\"width:90%; height: 40px; \">
<div id=\"message\"></div>
</form>
```

Here's my stay on page after submit code. I am using a script include to allow my stay on the same page after submit to work. It took me awhile to find a way to stay on same page after submit. If there is a better method for staying on the same page that works with clearing a form after submission by all means please share:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#msg').ajaxForm({
            target: '#message',
            success: function() {
            $('#message').fadeIn('slow');
            }
        });
    });


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#msg")[0].reset();
```

Put this inside  success: function()

so you get this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#msg').ajaxForm({
            target: '#message',
            success: function() {
     $("#msg")[0].reset();

            $('#message').fadeIn('slow');
            }
        });
    });


</script>
```

Comment: I would vote you 1 up but I need at least a 15 reputation. I am new here. Thanks for the simple and easy explanation. This I could apply with success instantly. A++++++++